# Anagram not matching up (string to list), Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, anagram

I'm trying to make a script where I can input an anagram of any word and it will read from a dictionary to see if there's a match
(ex. estt returns: = unjumble words: test)

If there are two matches it will write
(ex. estt returns: there are multiple matches: test, sett(assuming sett is a word lol)

I couldn't even get one match going, keeps returning "no match" even though if I look at my list made from a dictionary I see the words.

Here's the code I wrote so far

```
def anagrams(s):
    if s =="":
        return [s]
    else:
        ans = []
        for w in anagrams(s[1:]):
            for pos in range(len(w)+1):
                ans.append(w[:pos]+s[0]+w[pos:])
            return ans

dic_list = []
def dictionary(filename):
    openfile = open(filename,"r")
    read_file = openfile.read()
    lowercase = read_file.lower()
    split_words = lowercase.split()
    for words in split_words:
        dic_list.append(words)

def main():
    dictionary("words.txt")
    anagramsinput = anagrams(input("unjumble words here: "))
    for anagram in anagramsinput:
        if anagram in dic_list:
            print(anagram)
        else:
            print("no match")
            break
```

It's as if anagram isn't in dic_list. what's happening?

Comment: Can we see words.txt

Comment: I made it really small.  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4dH2vTP52jxMzJROXd5akNlOEtHbGl1bjl4TGI5OHkyMmQw/edit?usp=docslist_api

Comment: Did you verify that dic_list holds the correct values?

Comment: With what input word did you test?

Comment: what is `anagramsinput` supposed to be? I don't think your `anagrams` function does what you expect

Comment: I checked dic_list by doing print(dic_list) and it does show the words that I want.
I tried the word abbey, wrote it as bbeya.

anagrams function breaks the word up into anagrams and append it into a list, for example, test would give me [ttes, tset, estt, and so on] it scrambles the word up and will compare it to the dictionary to see if any of those words that are scrambled up have a match in the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are breaking after a single check in your loop, remove the `break` to get all anagrams:

```
def main():
    dictionary("words.txt")
    anagramsinput = anagrams(input("unjumble words here: "))
    for anagram in anagramsinput:
        if anagram in dic_list: # don't break, loop over every possibility
            print(anagram)
```

If you don't want to print no match just remove it, also if you want all possible permutations of the letters use `itertools.permutations`:

```
from itertools import permutations
def anagrams(s):
  return ("".join(p) for p in permutations(s))
```

Output:

```
unjumble words here: onaacir
aaronic
```

In your anagrams function you are returning before you finish the outer loop therefore missing many permutations:

```
def anagrams(s):
    if s =="":
        return [s]
    else:
        ans = []
        for w in anagrams(s[1:]):
            for pos in range(len(w)+1):
                ans.append(w[:pos]+s[0]+w[pos:])
        return ans # only return when both loops are done
```

Now after both changes your code will work

Comment: I don't want it to print
no match 5 times if I put a word that can be scrambled 5 times. If I don't put break I still get a "no match"

Comment: @Archie. you break the loop on the first iteration no matter what

Comment: Thanks, Maybe I could put the result it a list first. then do another no match statement after. I still can't get the code to work though, it gets nothing

Comment: I added output of running it with the permutations fucntion

Comment: So if it works when permutations code is put in, that means the problem lies within my anagrams(): function right? I'm trying to fix it rather than jumping to a different method. Sorry I'm still a beginner at this.

Comment: @Archie, you need to rearrange the letters in every possible permutation  to find all possible matched, you can make your own function but it is easier use itertools. One big problem you have is returning before the outer loop finishes

Comment: Ah, I see. It's the len(w) part that's making it leave before the loop finishes. I gotta figure out some sort of equation to make sure all the anagrams are generated.

Comment: Yes. You need to make sure you get the same output as my anagram function.

Comment: Now that I have it working, I'm moving on to permutations. Is there a way to make it faster, a word that's 6 letters in length(720 anagrams) of taking almost a minute to produce the result. Especially when I add the full dictionary to it, then turning it into a list.(almost 2MB)
(720 anagrams or more individually going through the dictionary 1 by 1 in a loop.)